# Differentiating vector by matrix, optimization problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, matrix-calculus, gradient-descent

I am currently writing a simulation, which includes an loss function at the end for optimization.

In order to perform backpropagation I need to calculate some derivatives.

My forward pass is the following function:
$$
s(\alpha, \beta)=N - \sum_{i=1}^{N}\prod_{j=1}^{E_{max}}1-sigm(\alpha*I_{i,j}+\beta*D_{i,j})
\\ ´\\ \text{with: } N, E_{max} \in \mathbb{N_0}, \\ \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}\\ I, D \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times E_{max}}
$$

**1. Is there a more concise way to calculate the row product of a matrix?**

While applying the chain rule I ran into the following issue:

$$
f_{i,j}(\alpha,\beta) :=  sigm(\alpha*I_{i,j}+\beta*D_{i,j})\\
g_{i,j}(f):=sigm(f)\\
m_i(g):= \prod_{j=1}^{E_{max}}1-g_{i,j} \\
s(m):= N-\sum_{i=1}^{N}m_i\\
L(s):= \frac{1}{2}*(y-s)^2
$$
If I want to optimize for $\alpha$, I need to calculate $\frac{dL}{d\alpha}$

So far I got:

$\frac{dL}{ds}=-(y-s)$

$\frac{ds}{dm}=[-1, \dots, -1]$

**2. But how can I get $\frac{dm}{dg}$?
If I am not mistaken I would have to differentiate a vector function $m$ by a matrix $g$?**

**3. Is there a better way to get the derivative of $s$ directly?**

Comment: Is $sigm(f)$ the elementwise logistic function, more commonly denoted $\sigma(f)\,$ ?

Comment: Oh I should have clarified, yes it is the sigmoid function. I did not know of this denotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\large\tt1}}
\def\p{{\partial}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\l{\big(}
\def\r{\big)}
\def\D{{\rm Diag}}
$Rename
some existing variables
$\big(I\to A,\;N\to n,\;E_{max}\to m\big)$
and define some new variables
$$\eqalign{
X &= \alpha A+\beta D
  \quad&\implies\quad dX = A\,d\alpha \\
F &= {\rm sigma}(X)
  \quad&\implies\quad dF = (J-F)\odot F\odot dX \\
G &= \log(J-F)
  \quad&\implies\quad dG = dF\oslash(F-J) \\
p &= \exp(G\o_m)
  \quad&\implies\quad dp = p\odot(dG\,\o_m) \\
P &= \D(p) \\
}$$
where $\o_n\in{\mathbb R}^{n}$ is the all-ones vector, $\,J=\o_n\o_m^T$ is the all-ones matrix, and the functions $(\log,\exp,{\rm sigma})$ are applied element-wise. The symbols $(\odot,\oslash)$ denote element-wise multiplication and division.

Write the remaining variables in terms of the new variables
$$\eqalign{
s &= n - \o_n:p
  \quad&\implies\quad ds = -\o_n:dp \\
L &= \tfrac 12(s-y)^2
  \quad&\implies\quad dL = (s-y)\,ds \qquad\qquad \\
}$$
Now it's just a matter of backsubstitution.
$$\eqalign{
dL &= (s-y)\,ds \\
 &= (y-s)\;\o_n:dp \\
 &= (y-s)\;\o_n:p\odot(dG\,\o_m) \\
 &= (y-s)\;p\o_m^T:dG \\
 &= (y-s)\;p\o_m^T:dF\oslash(F-J) \\
 &= (y-s)\,\l p\o_m^T\r\oslash(F-J):dF \\
 &= (y-s)\,\l p\o_m^T\r\oslash(F-J):(J-F)\odot F\odot(A\,d\alpha) \\
 &= (s-y)\,\l p\o_m^T\r\odot F:A\,d\alpha \\
 &= (s-y)\;PF:A\,d\alpha \\
 &= (s-y)\;{\rm Tr}(PFA^T)\,d\alpha \\
\grad{L}{\alpha} &= (s-y)\;{\rm Tr}(PFA^T) \\
}$$
where a colon is being used as a convenient product notation
for the trace, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|_F^2 \\
}$$
Note that the colon and element-wise products commute with themselves and each other
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A\odot B &= B\odot A \\
(A\odot B):C &= A:(B\odot C)
 \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\
}$$
The key idea is that the logarithm turns the product into a sum (which is easy to write in standard matrix notation) followed by exponentiation. Also, the [derivative of the logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Derivative) function is well-known.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time, everything was easily understandable. You helped me out tremendously. I'll keep the trick with taking the log first in mind.